# Magento 2.3.3 - JS not getting minifed

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, js-minification

Magento 2.3.3 - JS not getting minified

Project in prodcution mode and js minified activate.

CSS minified working properly but not JS.

https://snipboard.io/RZwqmC.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you have done to minify it and what makes you think it isn't being minified please?

Comment: you enable the js minified in backend ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but maybe you could try this:

```
bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 1
bin/magento config:set dev/css/minify_files 1
```

Reference with more information:

**https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Merged-JS-and-CSS-do-not-work-when-Production-mode/td-p/32023**

**[Magento 2 not minifying JS, CSS or HTML in Production Mode](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251861/magento-2-not-minifying-js-css-or-html-in-production-mode)**